# Modify terminal appearance

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

***I use Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS 64-bit and Visual Studio Code v 1.55***

Every time after I get an output from the terminal I get this text "*user@user-Aspire-5742G: **folder path here***" in the same line as what's supposed to output, so it would look something like this:

```
4 3user@user-Aspire-5742G:folder path here
```

My question is, can I somehow put an endline after "4 3" so I get the user@user part underneath it? It should look like this:

```
4 3
user@user-Aspire-5742G:folder path here
```

***prntscr of what's shown on the terminal***

[image: print screen of what's shown on the terminal]

Comment: Where does this "4 3" come from? Maybe the previously executed command simply omitted a trailing newline from its output? That said, there is something called a "shell prompt", which can be configured for most shells.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Hello! I've tried `PS1="$PS1\n"` at the end of `sudo nano /.bashrc` and this doesn't seem to solve the problem. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why did you use `sudo` to edit a file in the filesystem root dir (where it's not read for any user)? Let me repeat my question: Where does the output come from? There's too much info you simply don't provide which is necessary in order to reproduce (and understand!) what's going on. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]!